Use DBT in AWS to pull data from s3 and send them to RDS
I'm currently exploring the possibility of using dbt to process SQL data pulled from S3 and then storing them in RDS on PostgreSQL. These SQL data snapshots from S3 are occasional updates provided by my client, and my goal is to refine them into clean data within RDS, essentially creating datamarts. I want to run my dbt app with ECS.
Normally dbt does not have an adapter available for s3, I see that can run dbt-spark with EMR on s3 data? Is it my best solution, is my comprehension correct? Or is it a better idea to move out my sql s3 data to RDS before to apply dbt processes, with an existing adapters?

dbt simply runs commands in your designated database. Some databases know how to communicate with S3 (eg Snowflake, Databricks, Redshift, Athena). If you wan to refine/clean the data in the RDS database, then dbt should be pointed at that database. The issue then is how to load the data into the database. You could Import data from Amazon S3 into an RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance - Amazon Relational Database Service and then have dbt process that data.
